# How to apply Crystal Report parameter to only some of the fields in report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that currently pulls in all projects and their cost and then calculates their projected costs for the future. There is a time based parameter on the report that helps calculate the projection and limits the costs that are included based on the date. THE PROBLEM is that this parameter also excludes reports that are scheduled for the future that typically do not have any costs yet. I have tried to remove the time based parameter and it throws off the calculations. I have tried to apply the time based parameter to individual fields and the calculations are off(I might just be doing it wrong?) In Visual Studio I could just create two separate datasets and then link them on a key field within the same table but I don't know how to do something similar in Crystal. I have also wondered if a sub-report is the only way this can be done? I found this article, http://scn.sap.com/thread/1307121, but it doesn't seem to have a best answer selected.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: One solution is apply date parameter in report and apply time filtering inside the report

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how that would work.

Comment: If you apply your group filtering in select expert then only group data is retrived...so retrive all records and apply group filtering in teport